# Can we have the user page tabs on the flagging summary page?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, flag-history

When visiting the sites, I often check my profile page for any changes to:

- Flags I have submitted (and consequently my flag weight)
- Reputation changes
- Favourites

However, at the moment, when I want to check my flagging summary I have to navigate back to my profile by clicking my user name, rather than just changing tabs as I do between reputation and favourites:

[image]

I propose adding the profile page tabs to the flagging summary page, in order to keep the profile page consistent (and to improve my Stack Exchange navigation speed):

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [If I have flagged a post, show me a "flags" link in my profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199414/if-i-have-flagged-a-post-show-me-a-flags-link-in-my-profile)

Comment: As https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299245/208518 indicates, user profile pages changes make this request somewhat obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

Not a bad idea I think. But to make it more consistent, don't you think there should be a "Flagging" tab added to the tabs list?

However, since the flagging information is private, this should only be visible to the user when logged in, similar to "Flair" which is also not shown when not logged in.

Answer (score 2):

At some point the userpage tabs were moved down to the center, possibly making this feature request outdated.

[image: Moved tab location]