# If I have flagged a post, show me a "flags" link in my profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, profile-page

**The Problem**

Currently if I flag a post, I cannot check the status of the flag unless I have prior helpful flags. This means, for example, that a new user who wants to check the status of his *first* flag cannot do so while it is pending (active).

This feature request is based on my experience on MSO, where I wanted to check the status of my flag but could not get to the summary page without cheating (tweaking my SO link to work with MSO). It also stems from this question, where the OP indicates he had the same issue: [How to check the proceedings of a flagged post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199398/how-to-check-the-proceedings-of-a-flagged-post)

**My Proposal**

If I have flagged any post, then show me a "flags" link (red arrow in image below). If I have any helpful flags, then the number of helpful flags should be displayed (blue arrow). If I have not flagged anything, then neither should be displayed (as with current site functionality).

[image: profile-flags]

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [Link to flag summary is not shown if you have flagged for the first time but the flags have not been approved / rejected yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149537/link-to-flag-summary-is-not-shown-if-you-have-flagged-for-the-first-time-but-the)

Comment: Agree it's a dup, but that one is a bug report. This is a feature request. I just don't want this point to be lost.

Comment: You have no idea how much this annoys me as a moderator trying to look at the flag history for a user who has not had a handled flag.

Comment: Ok, admittedly I do prefer this one to the stated duplicate, so I'm retracting my close vote on this and voting for a reverse duplicate on the [bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149537/link-to-flag-summary-is-not-shown-if-you-have-flagged-for-the-first-time-but-the)

Comment: Wholeheartedly agreed.  We should make it as easy as possible for people to see their flag history, and it's especially important when *they're doing it wrong* (they've raised only unhelpful flags).  Yes, they'll now get a warning on future flags if they have rejected ones in the right quantity and timeframe, but let's give them a durable link that we can point to and encourage them to check.

Comment: This may be status-completed now. On woodworking.SE I just flagged my two first posts, and went to my profile and it showed link with text of "0 helpful flags" and I clicked on it and was able to see the two flags in pending status!

Comment: @Dro that's worth an answer... and don't forget FHRC ;)

Comment: Funny story... [my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256949/zero-helpful-flags-not-clickable) that was a dupe of this has been marked "status-complete" since July 17th.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though this is about the "old" profile page, the new one also has a flags section (in the "Activity" tab).

This one links to the flags page, even if none have been accepted yet.

Comment: [Not anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295374/always-link-to-flag-count)

Answer (score 37):

Instead of having conditional link placement depending on the state of your flag history, why not just add a flags tab? There's plenty of horizontal space remaining (even if you have a tiny monitor or like really skinny browser windows, other elements already force a horizontal scroll bar before the space is exhausted).

> [image]

Now there's no conditional logic, it raises visibility to flagging for new users, and if you don't have any flags yet the page shows up empty (just like most of the other tabs that don't have any relevant content to show).

Comment: That would work for me. I was just trying to minimize the work for the developers. While they are at it, they should make the flag summary more "pretty".

Comment: @chuex meh, my priority is on presenting information consistently, pretty can wait.

Comment: I would like this because maybe we would have this option on the mobile site.  The tabs appear to be part of the drop-down that we can select on the mobile version but we have no way to review our flag history mobilely _(i don't think that is a word but you get the point)_

Comment: +1 on this: @AaronBertrand why not enter it as a separate feature request?

Comment: And if we had a flags tab, then we could have sub-tabs for helpful, declined, and active, and then maybe it would be easier for us to [notice responses to flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226361/162102), and maybe we could even [get notifications of new responses](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172262/162102).