# Notification for when Community is about to delete a Question

Tags: feature-request, notifications, deleted-questions

I have been notified via [comments](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18849/what-was-tohsaka-doing-watching-the-dojo-lately/18883?noredirect=1#comment24371_18883) by another user that Community had been deleting a bunch of my questions.

> Hey, nothing to do with this post, but FYI, Community has been deleting a number of your old questions ([one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6907/how-did-suitengus-euphoria-virus-activate), [two](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/why-was-yui-happy-at-the-end), [three](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6919/what-are-reins-capabilities-with-others), and probably more you can see if you check [your recently deleted questions‌](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/1587)​). You might want to go through and undelete those.

Problem is it seems Community did this quite a while ago and if I use the [Recently Deleted Questions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/1587) link in the question area of my profile I find nothing.

This hasn't been the first time that I've noticed this and the annoying thing is that when Community Deletes a question there's not much I can do save edit and vote to delete. Not to mention I don't even know when it happened so I could have self answered a question that I may have posted and forgotten quite some time ago.

**Feature Request:**

A Notification of some method is sent to the owner of a question that it'll be deleted soon, this can give the owner time to see if they want to add a bounty in order to get it more noticed or add in more information.

Comment: An [update for recently deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247673/a-unified-solution-to-the-can-we-have-notifications-for-this-problem) might be useful. Notification, nah. Especially if it was deleted for a year of inactivity. To most users that would just be saying "this is going to be deleted" because they probably don't even remember why they asked the question at that point. A lot changes over a year.

Comment: Apparently a bounty [does not prevent Community deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247970/prevent-questions-with-bounty-to-be-auto-deleted), so adding a bounty to prevent deletion is going to need to happen soon enough to attract attention.