# Prevent questions with bounty from being auto-deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, bounties, deleted-questions

Originating from this question on Meta Stack Overflow ([Question about the name of a software design pattern was deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285128/question-about-the-name-of-a-software-design-pattern-was-deleted)), we wondered why a specific question was deleted, which met all requirements for deletion, but had a bounty on it.

As Mad Scientist sums up in that post, a question does quality for deletion, *even if it has a bounty on it*.

Currently, the requirements for deletion are:

> If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
>
> has −1 or lower score has no answers is not locked ...or...
>
> it was closed and migrated to a different site ... it will be
>   automatically deleted.

This seems undesired, even a bug to me.

Therefore, I suggest to add:

> Doesn't have an active bounty on it.

This prevents questions with bounties on it from being auto-deleted.

(As a side note: Questions that have a bounty can't be closed without intervention of a moderator, so why would the Community user delete an open question in this period?)

Comment: Seems logical, since users (except diamond mod?) cannot delete bountied question.

Comment: @AndrewT. technically that isn't a restriction.  Users can't close bountied questions (no one can, but mods can refund the bounty first then close it).  And users can't delete questions unless they are closed first.

Comment: @Andrew I strongly suspect that if somehow a bounty is started on closed question, 10k users will be able to cast delete votes as usual.

Comment: But they can't close it, so why would they be able to vote to delete?

Comment: @PatrickHofman because the restriction to prevent deletion was thought to be unnecessary.  Why check something that shouldn't occur?  Obviously `Community's` super powers do need to include a check as you proposed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We agree, questions that contain an active bounty should not be eligible for auto deletion.  This change will go out in the next build.  The same criteria applies after the bounty has ended so if the post still meets the above specifications after the bounty is over it will be removed.

Comment: Does it need a period to give OP the chance to put another bounty on it?

Comment: There is a natural grace period of one hour (give or take) due to this running on a scheduled task.

Comment: Bounty as a Life Support machine... cool! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Since you can't add a low bounty many times on a post, I don't see any problem. As you say: cool :)

Comment: @GeoffDalgas: In my opinion this could be a day too, but I don't think it is very important. Thanks for fixing this.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas: This seems to have regressed. MSO: [Question got deleted by community while having a bounty on it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304184/question-got-deleted-by-comunity-while-having-a-bounty-on-it). Timeline shows the question (which was bountied), was removed by the Community under "RemoveDeadQuestions".

Comment: Would you mind updating the roomba help page to reflect that? [I missed that info today...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345274/325771)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why override and approve the edit? It deleted the word "not", which completely changes the meaning of your post.