# Can questions with an active bounty on them roomba?

Tags: support, bounties

I came across a question today which was older than 30 days, had just 30 views, and gotten a bounty (from a third person) today. It adheres to all of the criteria for the [30 day roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba), therefore my question: can questions with an active bounty be automatically deleted by the roomba?

The dupe target does answer the issue: questions with an active bounty will not be automatically deleted. Can we fix the roomba help-page to reflect that? (If you're fixing it anyway, please also in-line the link to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310266/325771 at the end.)

Comment: Do you mean there's an active bounty? Then see here: [Prevent questions with bounty from being auto-deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247970/515960)