# Question with an active bounty was mistakenly deleted by the Roomba

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, deleted-questions, auto-delete

[How does Canada's radiotelescope CHIME manage polarization-dependent apodization of the fast f/0.25 optics?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28615/7982) was previously automatically deleted `RemoveAbandonedQuestions` and I'd recently found it [with assistance](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/670/7982)

I added a bounty to it to make sure it was now an active question and to try to encourage answers.

To my surprise it was *instantly re-deleted* after I applied the bounty, and it is now a deleted question again with a live bounty.

Per [Prevent questions with bounty from being auto-deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247970/377214), questions with an active bounty should not be deleted by the Roomba; it should not kick in until the bounty expires. But this question was still deleted despite that request being marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). It seems that doesn't seem to work anymore.

[image: screenshot of a very busy roomba!]

Comment: Per [Prevent questions with bounty from being auto-deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247970/377214), questions with an active bounty aren't supposed to be automatically deleted by the Roomba, so the fact that this question was deleted is a bug.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog my understanding is that the intended behavior is essentially a seven (or eight including the bounty grace period) day "pass" only, with the expectation of fairly quick insta-re-roombaing after that, is that a correct interpretation of that discussion? And if the question picks up some additional activity like an up vote during that period, re-roombaing is unlikely?

Comment: Yes, it's only exempt for so long as the bounty is *active*; once it expires, it will once again be eligible for potential automatic deletion if the criteria still apply, once the bounty *expires*.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog I see what you mean, thanks!

Comment: The banner has a link in the word "deleted", which leads to a webpage [with this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309526/282094) as it's penultimate link. Also, I voted to undelete.

Comment: @Rob it's open again, thank you... at least temporarily. Before the edit my question asked what I need to prevent re-roomba, I've made an edit but I think that is not enough.

Answer (score 8):

A fix for this bug is now live. The `RemoveAbandonedQuestions` scheduled job wasn't accounting for active bounties.

Noble bounty-ers, go forth and give those questions one last chance.

Comment: So, to be clear, the prior implementation only had this check in the `RemoveDeadQuestions` job?

Comment: Also, can the help center page on automatic deletion please be updated to reflect these changes?

Comment: go forth and [bountify](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/546030/217285)? Thank you for tracking this down and resolving it!

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Correct, `RemoveDeadQuestions` was the only weekly job that handled bounties. Also, I'll update the help center page to reflect this.