# Active bounty didn't prevent automatic deletion

Tags: bug, bounties, auto-delete

According to [Prevent questions with bounty from being auto-deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247970) an active bounty should prevent automatic deletion:

> We agree, questions that contain an active bounty should not be eligible for auto deletion. This change will go out in the next build. The same criteria applies after the bounty has ended so if the post still meets the above specifications after the bounty is over it will be removed.

I recently came across a [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/35279) on Database Administrators that seemed worthy of answers and added a 'draw attention' bounty to it.

While the bounty was still active, the question was deleted ([timeline](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/35279/timeline)):

> Scheduled: RemoveAbandonedQuestions