# Link to the flag history page on the flagging privilege page

Tags: feature-request, flags, flag-history, privileges-page

Users with 15 reputation points [are told that they can flag posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). This is great, and is a big part of helping the community moderate their sites.

However, some people have noticed that some users don't realize that their flags go anywhere, and [need be taught about flag responses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239353/266359). One place that they might be told about their flagging history is on the page where they're told that they have the privilege to flag -- last time I checked (just now), there was no mention of that history on the privilege page.

Best thing (I think) would be to include a direct link to that users flag-history page, but it would also be good just to mention it, possibly with a screenshot of someone's profile page with a mouse hovering over the link to the flag history.