# Zero helpful flags not clickable

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

On the new user profiles, there is a link for helpful flags. When you click on it, it takes you to your flagging summary.

If you have zero helpful flags, either because you've never flagged anything or because your flags are either pending or were not deemed helpful, it's not a link!

This should be a link regardless of whether you have any helpful flags or not. If you haven't flagged, it should just go to a blank page that says "This user has never flagged anything".

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce I did look for something similar. I agree it's asking the same thing but that one is for the old User pages rather than the new ones... not sure that matters.

Comment: I don't know that it does. There are a couple of other questions that were asking about the new user profile that were closed as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: New design, same bug - still a dupe.

Comment: @Oded How is this "completed"? as far as I can tell, the "0 flags" is simply gone, as there's now no content in the impact box...

Comment: Since this is closed, I could't post an answer. You will see the change in the next build.

Comment: @Oded could you add your answer to the [linked question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199414/if-i-have-flagged-a-post-show-me-a-flags-link-in-my-profile) and mark it as status complete?